# iOS AppStore :: how to get into the lists of daily new released apps for different languages?

Tags: ios, app-store, release

How does it work to get into the different countries daily generated list of new released apps? Lets say my app is made for english and german people. How does apple recognize that the app should be placed in both lists?

thnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple can read out the information how many localizations you have included and sets the info in the app description automatically.

Comment: this means I have to add .lproj-folders inside my ressources folder for each language I want the app to be on that list?